# Failed to create resource(s) when installing the latest version of MoonMail

Tags: moonmail

I got this error when installing MoonMail follow the default instructions. It's seem that the installation guide is out of date. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: sendCampaignTopicARN  
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: sendEmailsTopicARN  
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: sentEmailsTopicARN  
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: projectBucket  
/Users/michael/.node/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

ServerlessError: ServerlessError: An error occurred while provisioning your cloudformation: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AttachSenderTopic, PrecompileCampaignTopic, SentEmailsTable, SendCampaignTopic, PrecompileEmailTopic, AttachRecipientsTopic, ClicksStream, SentEmailsTopic, CampaignsTable, TemplatesTable, FreeUsersSendEmailQueue, UsersTable, IamRoleLambda, AttachListRecipientsTopic, StaticDataBucket, UnsubscribedRecipientTopic, LinksTable, UpdateListImportStatusTopic, EmailAdminsTopic, ListsTable, EmailNotificationsTopic, AttachRecipientsCountTopic, OpensStream, UpdateCampaignTopic, SendEmailsTopic, RecipientsImportS3Bucket, ReportsTable].
```

Comment: do you have access to AWS Web console, CloudFormation in particular?

Comment: would be nice if there was a list of variables that need to be defined in the s-variables-*.json file, since i'm getting warnings about 30+ different variables that are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy the project, you've got to define all those variables in the appropriate `s-variables-*.json` file. Besides, the issue could be somewhere else. I suggest you to go to the CloudFormation web console and check the events history for the MoonMail stack, it provides more information and better understanding about why it errored than the serverless CLI.

Comment: The CloudFormation console doesn't show anything, since there is no stack created.